# help with strange Double Integral: $\iint_E {x\sin(y) \over y}\ \rm{dx\ dy}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

i'm having trouble with this double integral:
$$
\iint_E {x\sin(y) \over y}\ \rm{dx\ dy},\ \ \ \ 
E=\Big\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid 0<y\le x\ \ \  \land\ \ \  x^2+y^2 \le \pi y\Big\}
$$
i've tried using polar coordinates, but after i made the domain normal i realized that the integrand got a lot more complicated..
then i've tried another transform: $u=y/x, v=y$; with even worse results.
i'm looking mainly for a tip on how to tackle this,
also i'd like to know the reasoning behind an eventual tip... thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps make a substitution to complete the square in $x^2 + y^2 \leq \pi y$ and convert the resulting coordinates to polar, and then hope for a serendipitous substitution?

Comment: i managed to solve it, the domain must be made y-normal and then it can be integrated with ease, thanks anyway

Comment: Could you post your answer?

Comment: What's the result? I wanna cross-check it with mine.

Comment: result: $$\pi - 2 \over 2$$

Comment: @FrancescoAlem. Perhaps you could post your worked solution as an answer to this question, for anyone else who might be interested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\iint_E {x\sin(y) \over y}\ \rm{dx\ dy},\ \ \ \ 
E=\Big\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid 0<y\le x\ \ \  \land\ \ \  x^2+y^2 \le \pi y\Big\}\\
\\
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2\le\pi y \iff x^2\le\pi y -y^2 \iff \vert x\vert \le \sqrt{\pi y -y^2}\\
0<y\le x
\end{cases} \implies \\
\implies 
0<y\le x \le \sqrt{\pi y -y^2} \implies 
\begin{cases} 
\sqrt{\pi y -y^2} \ge y \\
\pi y -y^2\ge 0\\
y >0
\end{cases}
\iff 0 < y \le \pi/2
$$
so now we have:
$$
0 < y \le \pi/2 \ \ \ \land \ \ \ y\le x \le \sqrt{\pi y -y^2}
$$
which gives us:
$$
\iint_E {x\sin(y) \over y}\ \rm{dx\ dy} = 
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\sin{y} \over y} \ \Big[ \int_{y}^{\sqrt{\pi y -y^2}} x\ \rm{dx} \Big] \rm{dy} = \cdots = {\pi-2 \over 2}
$$
you should be able to solve the single variable integrals yourself, also keep in mind that the integral is improper when y approaches 0.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the difficult one; $$x^2+y^2 \leq \pi y \iff x^2+y^2 -\pi y \leq 0$$ which is a circle(with all the points inside the circle, can't remember the english word) with center $C(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and radius $r=\frac{\pi}{2}$

You can parameterize this cirle as $$-\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}, \;  \frac12 (\pi-\sqrt{\pi^2-4 x^2)} \leq y \leq \frac12 (\sqrt{\pi^2-4 x^2}+\pi)$$

Now we have left;

$$0 <y \leq x$$

So $x$ has to be positive. Using the logical AND arguement, we have to combine these the solution from above with this one, thus $$0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$x \geq y$$ thus $$\frac12 (\pi-\sqrt{\pi^2-4 x^2)} \leq y \leq x \land 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$

The greater than instead of greater or equal than is throwing me off but I guess it could go like this(I may be wrong);

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{\frac12 (\pi-\sqrt{\pi^2-4 x^2)}}^x \frac{x\sin y}{y} \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x $$

Don't take my word for it though. It's my first time doing boundary conditions of this level. This was supposed to be a comment but it turned out rather long.

Comment: this is not very convenient, it's much better to solve the boundaries so that the first integration has to be carried out with respect to x. still thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Francesco Would you mind showing me your work? First time solving a problem like this, I just used my algebra knowledge and my intuition.

Comment: alright i'll post an answer to this...